# How to change Jbuttons image through if else statment?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

Really appreciated the help on last question, however ran into another problem was wondering if anyone could assist. On this programme I am trying to make a very basic treasure hunt game where the user has to click to find the treasure on a gui and when the button is clicked the picture of the button turns to a picture of a treasure chest. What my question is, I wanted to get the other buttons to change their picture to an empty hole but without overriding the treasure chest picture. I thought maybe an if/else statement could be used but would not know how to declare the not buttons[treasureHunt] variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import javax.swing.*;
     import java.util.Random;
     import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;



  public class Test extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

   JLabel label1, label2, label3;


   ImageIcon image1, image2, image3, image4, image5; 

   JTextField textResult; 

   JButton [] buttons; 

   int treasureLocation; 




   public static void main(String[] args) {



   new Test();

  }


   public Test (){

  this.setSize(700,700);
  this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setTitle("Treasure Hunt Game");

  JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();


  thePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,3,0,0));

  image1 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Treasure.jpg"));
  image2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Pirate.jpg"));
  image3 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("sand2.jpg"));
  image4 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("emptyhole.jpg"));   
  image5 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("map.jpg"));

  label1 = new JLabel("Click the buttons to find the Treasure!");
  label2 = new JLabel(image5); 
  label3 = new JLabel(image2);


  buttons = new JButton[9]; 
  buttons[0] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[1] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[2] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[3] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[4] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[5] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[6] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[7] = new JButton(image3);
  buttons[8] = new JButton(image3);





  thePanel.add(buttons[0]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[1]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[2]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[3]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[4]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[5]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[6]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[7]);
  thePanel.add(buttons[8]);
  thePanel.add(label1); 
  thePanel.add(label2);
  thePanel.add(label3);

  buttons[0].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[1].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[2].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[3].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[4].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[5].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[6].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[7].addActionListener(this);
  buttons[8].addActionListener(this);



  this.add(thePanel);

  this.setVisible(true);



  treasureLocation = new Random().nextInt(buttons.length);


   System.out.println(treasureLocation);

  }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){

    if (evt.getSource() == buttons[treasureLocation]) {


     buttons[treasureLocation].setIcon(image1);

   }
   else 

   }




  }



 }
```

Comment: Okay could you give some more information what exactly you want to do? Right now if a button is clicked and the button is the one with the treasure, the image of the button gets changed. Do you want all the other buttons to change their image as soon as the treasure was found?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear in the explanation. What I would like is the image of the clicked button to change to an empty hole if this is not the treasure chest location, this will simulate a turn. This will be a different picture to the treasure chest.

Comment: No problem Josh. Dont get me wrong, but you need to learn more fundamentals of java , e.g. read some books and do some step-by-step tutorials ;)

Comment: Haha as a matter of fact have order a few books to help me out with this. Just thought I'd see if you guys would help me out, which you have to the nth degree! Really appreciate help, cheers Ben.

Comment: You are welcome, its also a good motivation getting this simple example to work as your first program. Good luck for the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
{
   Object source = evt.getSource();
   if (source == buttons[treasureLocation]) {

      buttons[treasureLocation].setIcon(image1);
   }
   else 
   {
      ((JButton) source).setIcon(someImageFile);
   }
}
```

This should answer your question. The evt.getSource() returns the `object` which fired the event, in this case the button which got clicked. In `else` you have to cast it to `JButton` in order to change the Icon of it (= calling the `setIcon()` method).

You could actually also perform a cast if its the treasure, instead of retrieving the button over the index. I didnt change it because I could imagine that doing a cast is a more expensive task than just retrieving it over the index.